# Unable to use Google Geocoding to find bermuda city and county

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, google-geolocation

I'm trying to get the name of the city and county from a Bermuda postal code using the google geocoding.

If for example I issue this request:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:CA|postal_code:G2B4R7&sensor=false

I get the right answer for a canadian postal code, but if I want my bermuda postal code, I get no results, this is my request:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:BM|postal_code:GE05&sensor=false

I know this is a valid postal code.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What part of Bermuda is that? Can't seem to find anything with that kind of postalcode. Try with `administrative_area`?

Comment: In this spreadsheet says that there is such postal code: http://www.bpo.bm/Lists/Postal%20Codes/Attachments/1/Bermuda%20Postal%20Codes%20and%20Parishes%202013.pdf

Comment: Or you can use this service too: http://www.geopostcodes.com/bermuda_zip_codes

Comment: And this is only part of an algorithm that searches for the city and state/province for a given postal code and country, if I need to change the parameters based on the country then we start adding edge cases to the algorithm, as I know this geolocation based api is something generic